# Set sType to all aoColumns on dynamic jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm working on a huge custom datatable function and I've a simple issue, I need to set 'sType' to all 'aoColumns', but these tables are dynamic, so they may have 6 or 10 columns, and I can't find a way to do, I have already tried the following options:

```
//doesn't work
"aoColumns": [{"sType":"string", "aTargets": ["_all"]}],

//this works, but its not dynamic :/
"aoColumns": [{"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}],
```

and I can't do this using server-side

**obs.: I have a var with number of columns**

```
6 columns
"aoColumns": [{"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}],
10 columns
"aoColumns": [{"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}],
```

Thanks anyway

Comment: Are you initially building the table in php?

Comment: yes, but only the thead and search inputs, data is loaded using ajax

Comment: Count the columns you'll have with php before setting up the datatable value s, then use a while loop to create as many "{"sType":"string"}" as you need. Does that make sense?

Comment: I have the number of columns, but how do I create this while? I though about this but I cant think about this while..

Comment: are you returning a json object from the ajax, or html?

Comment: its returning an ajax
do you know the syntax in javascript to create this while?
for example:
while(columns > 0){
aocolumns[] = {"sType":"string"};
columns--;
}
something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server-side PHP: Well, If you are creating the table in php, then you should be able to build a string with all the needed array parts that you can plug into the javacript.

```
<?php
$colnum = 6;
$i = 1;

$aocolumns = array();

while($i <= $colnum){
  $aocolumns[] = '{"sType":"string"}';
  $i++;
}

$aocolumns = join(",",$aocolumns);
$aocolumns = '[' . $aocolumns . ']';

?>
```

then drop it in like

```
"aoColumns": <?=$aocolumns?>
```

Javascript: Assuming you get the columns back from the ajax as an array called "cols", you can try this for loop. :

```
var aocolumns = [];
for(i in cols){
  var ao = {"sType":"string"}; 
  aocolumns.push(ao);
}
alert(aocolumns);
```

Comment: sorry, I made an edit. Can you provide the string that the ajax call returns?

Comment: sorry, only the rows are obtained by ajax, columns are fixed, but it can vary depending on the table, take a look at the question, I've made an edit

Comment: I made an edit for a way to try it with php, not sure if that will work for you. Sorry, I feel like I'm not being real helpful. I hope this is giving some ideas at least.

Comment: I will use this as a solution for a while, but I'll keep trying to do this using only javascript, I have all javascript functions in one file, just to keep things separated, firm programmers rules haha
thanks for atemption and sorry for my english! :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are more complex than they need to be.

**Javascript version:**

```js
var i, aoColumns = [];
for (i = 0; i < totalCol; i++) {
  aoColumns.push( { 'sType': 'string' } );
}
```

**ECMAScript 6 version:**

```
aoColumns.fill( { 'sType': 'string' }, 0, totalCol )
```

This may work on your browser if a polyfill exists for the JavaScript `array.fill` command in any libraries you use.

**PHP (server side) version:**

```
<?php
//  array( 'stype' => "string" ); for old PHP
$columns = 6;
$aoColumns = array_fill( 0, $columns, [ 'stype' => 'string' ] );
print json_encode($aoColumns);
?>
```

Comment: In a few weeks time you'll be able to initialise by something like `aoColumns.fill( { 'sType': 'string' }, 0, totalCol ); (coming soon in ECMAScript 6)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using parseJSON and converting string to a JSON:

```
aoColumns = '[{"sType":"string"}';
i = 0;
tc = totalCol;
while(i<tc){
    aoColumns += ',';
    aoColumns += '{"sType":"string"}';
    i++;
}
aoColumns += ']';

// if totalCol == 3 then
// aoColumns will return [{"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}, {"sType":"string"}]
aoColumns = $.parseJSON(aoColumns);
```

this worked!