# setting a number unkonwn of columns of datatable jquery with specific type "formatted-num" dynamicaly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I want to set a number of columns of datatable with type "formatted-num". I can't use the static way because I don't know the number of columns; they are created dynamically. How can I accomplish this?
here is the way for a number known of columns :

```
"aoColumns": [
    null,
    null,
    { "sType": "formatted-num" },
    { "sType": "formatted-num" },
    { "sType": "formatted-num" },
    { "sType": "formatted-num" }
]
```

and here is my datatable js :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">  
    jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "formatted-num-pre": function ( a ) {
            a = (a==="-") ? 0 : a.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" );
            return parseFloat( a );
        },
        "formatted-num-asc": function ( a, b ) {
            return a - b;
        },
        "formatted-num-desc": function ( a, b ) {
            return b - a;
        }
    } );


    $(document).ready(function() {
        //   Init DataTables 
        $('#datatable').dataTable({
            "bPaginate"     : false,
            "bJQueryUI"     : true,
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

And here is my html code :

```
<table id="datatable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>nom</th>
            <?php for($i = 0 ; $i < $nbre ; $i++) { ?>
            <th><?php echo $nom[$i]; ?></th>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php for($i = 0 ; $i < $total ; $i++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $totals_ca[$i]['nom']; ?></td>
            <?php for($j = 0 ; $j < $nbre ; $j++) { ?>
            <td><?php echo $totals_ca[$i][$nom[$j]]; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Regards , thanks.

Comment: At very least, you're missing a `<tr>`

Comment: i've solved  like that :                                       for($i = 0 ; $i < $column ; $i++){
  $aocolumns[] = '{"sType":"formatted-num"}';
}                                                                   
$aocolumns = join(",",$aocolumns);
$aocolumns = '[' . $aocolumns . ']';                                                                 in the js : "aoColumns"     : <?=$aocolumns?>,                                                     reference to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156230/set-stype-to-all-aocolumns-on-dynamic-jquery-datatable